# gstreamer playbin only video

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, gst-launch, audiovideoplayback

I am using the following pipeline

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file:///mnt/hash.mp4 video-sink="imxv4l2sink" flags=0x57
```

This works fine for the video file ( mp4 ) which doesn't have video in it. But when I pass a mp4 file which has both video and audio it fails to play.

Can you please help me in reconstructing the pipeline to allow it to work on both kind of files: MP4 with only video, MP4 with both audio and video

Comment: could you attach a small mp4, which doesn’t work ?

Comment: any video with audio is not working

Comment: Try the following pipeline (make sure you change the xvimagesink, and also make sure you have all the plugins installed which are used in the pipeline):  gst-launch-1.0 -m filesrc location=1.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! level message=true ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demux. ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink

Comment: No. I don't want to play audio, as I don't have audio codec working in the board. This pipeline is working :   gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=Images/hash.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vpudec !  imxv4l2sink. But we have already code using playbin2 plugin.. So I was thinking, if we can change something in the playbin2 to make it work

Comment: you would need to update your gstreamer to 1.0 and use playbin instead. (playbin2 should ideally create the pipeline (qtdemux ! vpudec ! imxv4l2sink)) look at the logs and see what elements it is creating.

Comment: Sorry. I cannot use gstreamer 1.0.. How to check that what is the pipeline constructed by playbin2

Comment: use gst-launch-0.10 -vvv

Comment: Can you explain me the significance of flags field used in the above pipeline

Comment: It's using vpudec, aiurdemux and sink

Comment: aiurdemux is nxp specific you need to check with them https://community.nxp.com/thread/335794

Comment: Can we change the default demux in playbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve by changing the value of flags field to disable audio.[image]

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file:///mnt/hash.mp4 video-sink="imxv4l2sink" flags=0x51
```